# How to save a CSV to a local directory in Python

Tags: python, csv, download

I'm very new to Python. I just created a CSV file with Python, and now I'd like to save it to a directory on my drive so I can access it with Excel, SAS, etc. How do I do this? Here is my code:

```
directory='C:\Users\Documents\pyth\tweet_sentiment.csv'
output=zip(tweets_list, positive_counts) #brings the two variables together for merging to csv
writer=csv.writer(open(directory, 'wb'))     
writer.writerows(output) #sends list to the csv
```

When I run this, I get an error:

> IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'C:\Users\Documents\pyth\tweet_sentiment.csv'

What should I do?

Comment: What's your code to do that?

Comment: OP, check my post on revisions to your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how you made your csv file, if it didn't save it automatically. Using the csv module, you can open/create a file and write a csv file at that location. It's automatically saved.

```
import csv
with open('pathtofile','wb') as csvFile: #EDIT - because comment.
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerows(csvstff)
```

If you could post your code, we'd probably be more able to help you.

```
directory='C:\Users\Documents\pyth\tweet_sentiment.csv'
```

Needs to be

```
directory='C:\Users\Documents\pyth\\tweet_sentiment.csv'
```

\t is tab. You need to escape that "\". In fact, for file directories, it's probably safer to use \ for all your \'s.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response. I just posted my code in my question.

Comment: AMAZING! Thank you so, so much. I've literally been struggling with this for 36 hours. You are my hero!

Answer (score 3):

See here: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Example of how to write to a file called `workfile`:

```
f = open('workfile', 'r+')
f.write('0123456789abcdef')
```